# Is there a significant speed improvement when using transformers tokenizer over batch compared to per item?

Tags: pytorch, huggingface-transformers

is calling tokenizer on a batch significantly faster than on calling it on each item in a batch? e.g.

```py
encodings = tokenizer(sentences)
# vs
encodings = [tokenizer(x) for x in sentences]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i ended up just timing both in case it's interesting for someone else

```
%%timeit
for _ in range(10**4): tokenizer("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.")
785 ms ± 24.5 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
%%timeit
tokenizer(["Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."]*10**4)
266 ms ± 6.52 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: I would also suggest to ensure that you're using a [Fast Tokenizer](https://huggingface.co/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer.html#transformers.PreTrainedTokenizerFast) when possible to gain a further speedup.